# Segmentation fault when trying dynamically allocate 2d char array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I have written the next similar example when I get a segmentation fault error

```
{
    const char** var = NULL;
    const char* tmp = "Hello! How are you?";
    var = (const char**)malloc(5 * sizeof(char*));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  
    {
        var[i] = (char*)malloc(50* sizeof(char));
        strcpy((char*)var[i], tmp);
    }
    for (int i = 0; var[i]; i++)
    {
        std::cout << (long int)var[i] << std::endl;
        std::cout << var[i] << std::endl;
    }
    // Free memory
    ....
    
}
```

And on the 6th iteration, for loop doesn't stop (I expected then var[i]==NULL) and I get the "Segmentation fault" error. Can you explain what I am doing wrong, please?

Comment: Where does this crash? This is where a debugger helps.

Comment: This isn't C, either. It appears to be C++, so retagged accordingly.

Comment: Why would you expect `var[6] == NULL`?

Comment: As pointed by Peter, out of your belongings memory can be anything, not necessarily NULL.

Comment: Is the intent of `(long int)var[i]` to perform a string to integer conversion, or to represent that pointer as a number just to see what it happens to be?

Comment: Why is `var` `const char**` and not just `char**`? Those const-casts in your code are at least very misleading (I would say terrible).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This walks off the end of the array:

```c
for (int i = 0; var[i]; i++)
```

Accessing `var` out of bounds is undefined behaviour, which *can* lead to a crash. You won't get a nice, neat value when you exceed the bounds like you might in JavaScript, Python or Ruby, you get *problems*. Unfortunately there's no checks for this, so you must be vigilant about not doing it inadvertently, the responsibility is on you.

Since you're apparently using C++ there's a lot of things you can fix here:

- Don't use C arrays if you can avoid it, use `std::vector`
- Don't use C strings if you can avoid it, use `std::string`

Combining this advice you get:

```cpp
const std::string tmp = "Hello! How are you?";

std::vector<std::string> var;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var.push_back(tmp);
}

for (auto& v : var) {
  std::cout << v << std::endl;
}

// No need to free memory, it's already handled for you.
```

When you're writing C++, try and enjoy the [Standard Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). It will make your life *significantly* easier than leaning heavily on error-prone C techniques.

Comment: But how I can do it in C-style?

Comment: You do it *very carefully* and make a point to never, **ever** walk off the end of an array. Always keep track of the maximum index you can use. Normally this is done by having a `size` variable, though there are other ways, like `const` values. It really depends on what the context is.

Comment: This is like driving on a mountain road with a very steep drop on the one side and absolutely no barrier. How do you not drive off the mountain? You pay very careful attention to what you're doing.